# Swift 3 Implementing SideMenu control without Storyboard(hardcoded)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I'm trying to implement this control: [Side Menu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu)
It say's that i need to instatiate it in the storyboard:

```
let menuLeftNavigation = Controllerstoryboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftMenuNavigationController") as! UISideMenuNavigationController
```

But I don't have a storyboard and I already created a UINavigationController (see below) So that I can use the module:

```
SideMenuManager.menuLeftNavigationController = menuLeftNavigationController
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let featuredVideosController = FeaturedVideosController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:featuredVideosController) //Required

    }
```

I'm currently stucked here. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `FeaturedVideosController`'s `viewDidLoad` method, add:

```
let menuLeftNavigationController = UISideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: YourMenuContentViewController)
menuLeftNavigationController.leftSide = true
SideMenuManager.menuLeftNavigationController = menuLeftNavigationController
```

Check more detail in [Side Menu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu)'s **Code Implementation** section.

Comment: I see, so how can I make a "YourMenuContentViewController"

Coz I tried creating a swift file:

`class SideMenuViewController: UISideMenuNavigationController 
{}`

then calling it in viewDidLoad:
 `let menuLeftNavigationController = UISideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: SideMenuViewController)`

Comment: It says `cannot convert value of type SideMenuViewController.Type to expected argument type UIViewController`. What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: You cannot directly use a class name. Create an instance first: `let sideMenuViewController = SideMenuViewController()`, then put this instance into part:  `rootViewController:sideMenuViewController`